# Back up option under system settings

Tags: 14.04, backup

I just used the back up option under system settings to back up my entire system. I did that in my home directory and created a folder with .gpg files under deja-dup. What is this sort of back up and how can i retrieve my backed up files if  want to from this folder.

Help!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Déjà Dup` is an incremental back-up utility which means it will back up all the files that have changed since the last backup.

To restore a backup, click the `Restore` button in the `Déjà Dup` window. It will automatically show you the folder that you last backed up to (or you can select the one you want). See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/) for a tutorial.